# Why does the following code give different results when compiling with gcc and g++?

Tags: c, gcc, g++, constants

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a=1;
    int *p=(int *)&a;
    (*p)++;
    printf("%d %d\n",*p,a);
    if(a==1)
      printf("No\n");//"No" in g++.
    else
      printf("Yes\n");//"Yes" in gcc.
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives `No` as output in `g++` compilation and `Yes` in `gcc` compilation. Can anybody please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you asking "Why is this allowed to happen?" or "I know anything is allowed to happen, but what mechanism inside the compiler makes *this particular* thing happen?"?

Comment: @immibis I guess the later one "I know anything is allowed to happen, but what mechanism inside the compiler makes this particular thing happen?"

Comment: @RohitChauhan , read the answers.

Comment: @ArunA.S The answers answer the first meaning of the question, not the second.

Comment: What do you want to possibly achieve with this code?

Comment: If you want an answer to the second meaning, it might be worth asking the question again, but adding that you already know it's undefined behaviour, and you want to know how the compiler internally arrives at this result. (But who knows how Stack Overflow works). Obviously, only do that if you're interested in the internals of compilers, not just in writing C or C++ programs.

Comment: @RohitChauhan , How do you expect us to know how the compiler does that. You would have to ask the person who programmed the compiler. This is not defined in the c or c++ standard, so it depends on the compiler and how it optimizes this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [newbie question: c++ const to non-const conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311041/newbie-question-c-const-to-non-const-conversion)

Comment: Which versions of `g++` and `gcc` are you using?  Also, what command line options did you use to compile the code? I expect that `g++` is replacing `a` with the literal constant `1` in the `if`, but `gcc` is not.

Comment: @MohitJain not really

Comment: Another similar one would be [changing the value of const variable in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006161/changing-the-value-of-const-variable-in-c). SO is full of similar question.

Answer (score 10):

Your code triggers undefined behaviour because you are modifying a `const` object (`a`). It doesn't have to produce any particular result, not even on the same platform, with the same compiler.

Although the exact mechanism for this behaviour isn't specified, you may be able to figure out what is happening in your particular case by examining the assembly produced by the code (you can see that by using the `-S` flag.) Note that compilers are allowed to make aggressive optimizations by assuming code with well defined behaviour. For instance, `a` could simply be replaced by `1` wherever it is used.

Answer (score 6):

From the C++ Standard (1.9 Program execution)

> 4 Certain other operations are described in this International
>   Standard as undefined (**for example, the effect of attempting to
>   modify a const object**). [ Note: This International Standard imposes
>   no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined
>   behavior. —end note ]

Thus your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, notice following two lines

```
const int a=1;        // a is of type constant int
int *p=(int *)&a;     // p is of type int *
```

you are putting the address of a `const int` variable to an `int *` and then trying to modify the value, which should have been treated as `const`. This is not allowed and invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For your reference, as mentioned in chapter 6.7.3, `C11` standard, paragraph 6

> **If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a `const`-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-`const`-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.** If an attempt is
>   made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined

So, to cut the long story short, you cannot rely on the outputs for comaprison. They are the result of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do you know when this made it into C ? Because it changes the definition of const variables significantly from ye-old-days. Before the compiler had to prove that a const flagged variable was not being changed elsewhere before it could reuse a copy. In this version it has been redefined to be basically an alias of 'restrict' so the compiler will now assume the variable will not be aliased for the whole time it's in scope. This would appear to make 'const' less useful, perhaps even something to be avoided because it invokes 'unreasonable behaviour'.

Answer (score 1):

Okay we have here 'identical' code passed to "the same" compiler but once
with a C flag and the other time with a C++ flag. As far as any reasonable
user is concerned nothing has changed. The code should be interpreted
identically by the compiler because nothing significant has happened.

Actually, that's not true. While I would be hard pressed to point to it in
a standard but the precise interpretation of 'const' has slight differences
between C and C++. In C it's very much an add-on, the 'const' flag
says that this normal variable 'a' should not be written to by the code
round here. But there is a possibility that it will be written to
elsewhere. With C++ the emphasis is much more to the immutable constant
concept and the compiler knows that this constant is more akin to an
'enum' that a normal variable.

So I expect this slight difference means that slightly different parse
trees are generated which eventually leads to different assembler.

This sort of thing is actually fairly common, code that's in the C/C++
subset does not always compile to exactly the same assembler even with
'the same' compiler. It tends to be caused by other language features
meaning that there are some things you can't prove about the code right
now in one of the languages but it's okay in the other.

Usually C is the performance winner (as was re-discovered by the Linux
kernel devs) because it's a simpler language but in this example, C++
would probably turn out faster (unless the C dev switches to a macro
or enum
and catches the unreasonable act of taking the address of an immutable constant).