# pointer const inside a scope, and non const outside

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am wondering how I can have a pointer const inside a scope, and non const outside.

I read several topics and web pages including [newbie question: c++ const to non-const conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311041/newbie-question-c-const-to-non-const-conversion) and [What's the point of const pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715371/whats-the-point-of-const-pointers)
The message I heard is "If you need to cast const to non-const, it's dangerous, and your code is likely poorly designed". However, I am not sure how to overcome this :

What I have now :

```
void compute(const CArray<FOO> &fooArray, CArray<double> &Results)
{
    Results[0] = 0.0 ;
    for(INT_PTR i=0 ; i<fooArray.GetCount()-1 ; ++i)
    {
        const FOO *foo1 = fooArray[i] ;
        DoSomething(foo1) ; //BOOL method which needs a const *FOO as parameter

        const FOO *foo2 = fooArray[i+1] ;
        DoSomething(foo2) ; //BOOL method which needs a const *FOO as parameter

        double res = 0.0 ;
        Compare(foo1, foo2, res) ; //Compare(const FOO *foo1, const FOO *foo2, double &result)
        Results[i+1] = res ;
    }
}
```

But `DoSomething` is a quite greedy function, and I'd like avoiding to call it twice on the same object. So I'd like to do something similar than this :

```
void compute(const CArray<FOO> &fooArray, CArray<double> &Results)
{
    const FOO *foo1 = fooArray[0] ;
    Results[0] = 0.0 ;
    DoSomething(foo1) ; //BOOL method which needs a const *FOO as parameter
    for(INT_PTR i=1 ; i<fooArray.GetCount() ; ++i)
    {
        const FOO *foo2 = fooArray[i] ;
        DoSomething(foo2) ; //BOOL method which needs a const *FOO as parameter

        double res = 0.0 ;
        Compare(foo1, foo2, res) ; //Compare(const FOO *foo1, const FOO *foo2, double &result)
        Results[i] = res ;
        *foo1 = *foo2 ; //what i would like to do, but I can't since *foo1 and *foo2 are const
    }
}
```

I 'could' remove all the const but as mentionned in the  topics I read, there is a good reason they are here : `DoSomething` and `Compare` are not supposed to modify `*foo1` and `*foo2`.

Comment: Make a function that returns const ptr, but inside uses non-const ptr?

Comment: You can pass non-const arguments to functions that take const arguments. When a function signature has const arguments it means it promises not to modify them. That is not a problem for modifyable arguments.

Comment: @kamikaze Well that's embarassing.. I guess sometimes I just need a fresh eye on my code. Ty for bringing me back on earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I 'could' remove all the const

You could indeed, and that would be the solution to your 'problem'. Although making `foo1` a pointer to non-const is sufficient.

> DoSomething and Compare are not supposed to modify *foo1 and *foo2.

Therefore they should take their parameters either by value, or by const reference (or a pointer to const, if that makes sense for some reason). In either case, it's OK to pass a non-const reference/object (or pointer to non-const) to the function.

> pointer const inside a scope, and non const outside

What you want is a pointer that is `const` within a few function calls, and non-const outside the functions. That is achieved simply as I described: Use a const reference (or a value, which doesn't need to be const) parameter, and pass your non-const variable to the function.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I just needed the pointer to be const inside the functions calls and non const outside. Maybe should I edit title ? ty anyway